# A question about Hermite coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, integral-inequality, hermite-polynomials

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be square-integrable w.r.t the standard normal distribution $N(0,1)$. For $G \sim N(0, 1)$, let $\sigma_0(f) := E_G[f(G)]$ and $\sigma_1(f) := E[Gf(G)]$ be the first 2 Hermite coefficients of $f$.

> **Question.** What is a characterization of functions $f$ for which $\sigma_0(f^2) \ge \sigma_0(f)^2 + \sigma_1(f)^2$ ?

### Observation

> Note that for any $f \in L^2(\mathbb R,N(0,1))$, then
> $$
> \sigma_0(f^2) \ge \max(\sigma_0(f)^2,\sigma_1(f)^2).
> \tag{*}
> $$

Indeed, by Cauchy-Schwarz, $\sigma_1(f)^2 := E[Gf(G)]^2 \le E[G^2]E[f(G)^2] = E[f(G)^2] = \sigma_0(f^2)$, i.e
$\sigma_0(f^2) \ge \sigma_1(f)^2$.
Also, since the variance of the r.v $f(G)$ is nonnegative, we have $\sigma_0(f^2) \ge \sigma_0(f)^2$.

- ***Even functions.*** As noted below by user Clement C., if $f$ is even (meaning $f(-x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$), then the inequality holds. Indeed, for such $f$, we have for $G \sim N(0,1)$,
  $$
  \sigma_1(f) = E[Gf(G)] = E[Gf(-G)] = E[-Gf(G)] = -\sigma_1(f),
  $$
  and so $\sigma_1(f) = 0$. Thus, the sought-for inequality then follows from (*).
- ***Odd functions.*** Similarly, i turns out that the inequality holds true if $f$ is odd. Indeed for such $f$, we have
  $\sigma_0(f) = E[f(G)] = E[-f(-G)] = -E[f(-G)] = -E[f(G)]=-\sigma_0(f)$,
  and so $\sigma_0(f)=0$. Thus, the sought-for inequality then follows from (*).

Comment: Definitely not an answer, but this will hold for any even $f$, for instance -- right?

Comment: I feel I'm missing something, so my apologies if that's the case... Wouldn't that last inequality not be simply that the "variance of f(G) is nonnegative"?

Comment: Indeed, I was the one missing something. Never though I would ever forget that variance is always nonnegative! Thus you're right the inequality holds if $f$ is even!

Comment: Similarly, i turns out that the inequality holds true if $f$ is odd. Indeed for such $f$, we have $\sigma_0(f) = E[f(G)] = E[-f(-G)] = -E[f(-G)] = -E[f(G)]=-\sigma_0(f)$, and so $\sigma_0(f)=0$. The core inequality then becomes $\sigma_0(f^2) \ge \sigma_1(f)^2$, which follows directly from Cauchy-Schwarze like so $\sigma_1(f)^2 := E[Gf(G)]^2 \le E[G^2]E[f(G)^2] = E[f(G)^2] =: \sigma_0(f^2)$.

Comment: Nice! ${}{}{}{}$